# `eccodes` library not found

Tags: python, conda, eccodes

I have installed the `eccodes` library using Conda, but when I try to import it in Python I get "*Cannot find the ecCodes library*".

Why do I get this error and how can I resolve it? I think that Python does not know where to find the library.

I used [the commands found here](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/UDOC/How+to+install+ecCodes+with+Python+bindings+in+conda+-+ecCodes+FAQ). That is,

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge eccodes
pip3 install --upgrade eccodes
```

I am using a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

After asking a colleague we found a solution by running the code

```
import ecmwflibs
```

Now eccodes is recognised

He found this because the error message was raised by the script in
~/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/gribapi/bindings.py

```
#
# (C) Copyright 2017- ECMWF.
#
# This software is licensed under the terms of the Apache Licence Version 2.0
# which can be obtained at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
#
# In applying this licence, ECMWF does not waive the privileges and immunities
# granted to it by virtue of its status as an intergovernmental organisation nor
# does it submit to any jurisdiction.
#

# Authors:
#   Alessandro Amici - B-Open - https://bopen.eu
#   Shahram Najm - ECMWF - https://www.ecmwf.int
#

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import logging
import pkgutil

import cffi

__version__ = "1.4.2"

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    import ecmwflibs as findlibs
except ImportError:
    import findlibs

library_path = findlibs.find("eccodes")
if library_path is None:
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot find the ecCodes library")

# default encoding for ecCodes strings
ENC = "ascii"

ffi = cffi.FFI()
CDEF = pkgutil.get_data(__name__, "grib_api.h")
CDEF += pkgutil.get_data(__name__, "eccodes.h")
ffi.cdef(CDEF.decode("utf-8").replace("\r", "\n"))


lib = ffi.dlopen(library_path)
```

Comment: why was this an issue? was the "import eccodes" not also doing the "import ecmwflibs"?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess with Pip here. Conda Forge provides both the compiled library (`eccodes`) and the Python bindings (`python-eccodes`). The latter lists the former as a dependency, so it should be sufficient to use:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge python-eccodes
```

Comment: Why not use pip? it is the default way to install 3rd party no?

anyway i will try your suggestion and seei if it works

Comment: The primary motivation for Conda is it’s ability to handle non-Python dependencies. That way, the SAT solver understands the full dependency graph. Using Pip for the bindings, leaves a gap.

Comment: still cannot find the library :-(